# Deploy application in GAE without Google account

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment

I learned Google App Engine by creating some simple application using **Java**.
I came to know that Google App Engine use google account like gmail, to deploy those application. I had deployed those application with my account(a gmail account). In some place Google account are blocked in Colleges, Schools, Companies, but they will allow some other mailing website like Outlook. I am also having email account like Outlook, Is it possible to deploy application with other email id like Outlook account?, if yes, how to deploy it.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to register for an Google cloud account

Comment: Thanks for the response @Palsri There is no way to deploy application without Google cloud account, this is disappointing. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's mandatory to sign for Google cloud like you have  to sign up on aws to deploy an app on aws

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fully understand your use case but note that you can add a new user to the project you want to deploy to by going to the [IAM & Admin](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) page in your Developer Console and add a new user with your Outlook email address and give him the owner role (or more [fine-grained permissions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control) if you prefer).

Then, to deploy your app, from your local machine for example, you can authenticate your gcloud (`gcloud init` or `gcloud auth login`) with this new account and run `gcloud app deploy` as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the response @LundinCast I would try with this, Thanks